# What are these fungi growing next to my cucumber plant?

Tags: identification, mushrooms

I believe I am having mushrooms growing with my cucumbers.

What are they?

[image]

Comment: Erm.... one question per post, please? And do you want an id or something else? For an id, more & detailed photos would be helpful, thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The little toadstools or mushrooms are just one of the Parasola inkcaps -  they don't last long and are a common inhabitant where there are bark chips in borders. They will cause no harm to your cucumber plants or you, so long as you don't attempt to eat them. An example of a Parasola mushroom here 
http://www.first-nature.com/fungi/parasola-auricoma.php.